# How to combine given dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have 2 dataframes train and user_features. 'user_features' has node_id (corresponding to node1_id and node2_id in train/test files) representing the user for whom we have features from f1 to f13. I want to transform 'train' such that it contains features from f1 to f13 of both node1_id and node2_id respectively.

```
train.head()
    node1_id  node2_id  is_chat
0   8446602   6636127        0
1   1430102   7433949        0
2   2803017   8372333        0
3   4529348    894645        0
4   5096572   4211638        0

user_features.head()
    node_id  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9  f10  f11  f12  f13
0      2     14  14  14  12  12  12   7   7   7    0    0    0   15
1      3     31   9   7  31  16  12  31  15  12   31   15   12    8
2      4      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    7
3      5     31   4   1  31   7   1  31   9   1   31    9    0   15
4      6     31  27  20  31  24  14  31  20  10   31   20    5    7
```

The expected transformed 'train' should be:

```
train.head(1)
    node1_id  node2_id  is_chat f1 f2 ...f13 f14 f15 ...f26
0   8446602   6636127        0  14 14 ... 31  4   1   ...10
```

Where the features from `f1 to f13` are of `node1_id : 8446602` and from `f14 to f26` are of `node2_id : 6636127` respectively. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

train_data = StringIO("""node1_id node2_id is_chat
8446602 6636127 0
1430102 7433949 0
2803017 8372333 0
4529348 894645 0
5096572 4211638 0""")

features_data = StringIO("""node_id f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13
2 14 14 14 12 12 12 7 7 7 0 0 0 15
3 31 9 7 31 16 12 31 15 12 31 15 12 8
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
5 31 4 1 31 7 1 31 9 1 31 9 0 15
6 31 27 20 31 24 14 31 20 10 31 20 5 7""")

train_df = pd.read_csv(train_data, sep=" ")
features_df = pd.read_csv(features_data, sep=" ")
```

Comment: So you are matching them on `index`? So index 0 of train is matched with index 0 of user_features?

Comment: No, I want to merge them on id's. node1_id and node2_id in train both are corresponding to node_id in the user_features.

Comment: Could you explain how you meatched node_id's `8446602 and 6636127` with node_id `2` from user_features?

Comment: No, I didnt do that. Those features are of node_id : 8446602(from f1 to f13) and node_id : 663612 (from f14 to f26) and were randomly generated by me.

Comment: I understand that you generated it. So there is no logic behind the matching? How do we match the `node_id` of `train` with `node_id` from `user_features`? What is the logic behind that. We cannot "randomly" match id's, that would not make sense

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

`.merge()` using `left_on` and `right_on` named params to specify desired merge columns.

The data was ambiguous, so this answer considers modified input data that is merge-able.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

train_data = StringIO("""node1_id node2_id is_chat
8446602 6636127 0
1430102 7433949 0
2803017 8372333 0
4529348 894645 0
5096572 4211638 0""")

features_data = StringIO("""node_id f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13
6636127 14 14 14 12 12 12 7 7 7 0 0 0 15
8446602 31 9 7 31 16 12 31 15 12 31 15 12 8
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
5 31 4 1 31 7 1 31 9 1 31 9 0 15
6 31 27 20 31 24 14 31 20 10 31 20 5 7""")

train_df = pd.read_csv(train_data, sep=" ")
features_df = pd.read_csv(features_data, sep=" ")

print(train_df.merge(features_df, left_on="node1_id", right_on="node_id").merge(features_df, left_on="node2_id", right_on="node_id"))
```